# How does Zerilli come up with this solution?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

I am studying the paper "[Gravitational field of a particle falling in a Scharzschild geometry analyzed in tensor harmonics](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.2.2141)" by Zerilli. The author calculates the gravitational radiation emitted by a particle falling along a geodesic into a Schwarzschild black hole.

In the appendix I, the author calculates the spectrum of the gravitational wave radiation emitted by a mass falling radially into a Schwarzschild black hole. It seems he is using a Green's function method, but how does he come up with the solution given in eqn. (I10)? Where do the $\tilde{c}_1$ and $\tilde{c}_2$ come from? It is really unclear.

Comment: He defines $\tilde{c}$ in the following lines after eqn I10. But I haven't looked at the derivation yet.

Comment: I think I have understood the procedure up to equation I5 and equation I10 is clear: what I do not understand is how to match two procedures, how to get the Green functions fron I5.